# Format input field to separate the first 4 digits with a period, and the next 2 digits with a period

Tags: javascript

I have a text-input with a placeholder value. Im wondering if it is possible to have a default value when the user clicks the input. The value should look like this: `____.__._____`

The `_` character in the value should be replaced with what the user is typing, but the period should stay in place.

Here is my input:

```
<input type="text" id="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" placeholder="Located on your card" />
```

Comment: Isn't this the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003524/separate-placeholder-text-in-forms-input-field-with-input-string-in-the-middle?rq=1

Comment: No, it is not. But thank you.

Comment: you could use a plugin for this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: @Ram Yes! Thank you! Add it to an answer!

Comment: @Garreth00, sorry mis-read it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a plugin for this:

[Masked Input plugin](http://www.digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin)

Comment: Thanks!. When i'm setting a value to the text box, the mask not applied.. Any Suggestion plz? And when i click inside the text box the value is gone..

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion involves two fields. One over each other. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/UCPxU/

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="template" value="____.__._____" />
<input type="text" id="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" placeholder="Located on your card" />
```

CSS

```
input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
input[name="accountnumber"] {
    background: none;
}
```

JS

```
var input = $("input[name='accountnumber']");
input.on("keyup", function(e) {
    var value = input.val();
    // catching backspace
    if(e.keyCode === 8) {
        if(value.length == 4) {
            input.val(value.substr(0, 3));
        } else if(value.length == 7) {
            input.val(value.substr(0, 6));
        }
    } else {
        if(value.length == 4) {
            input.val(value + ".");
        } else if(value.length == 7) {
            input.val(value + ".");
        }
    }
});
```

However, the solution works only if the user types every letter separately. If he for example press and hold 3 the keyup event is fired once, but the added characters are several. Anyway, this could be workarounded with setInterval or something like that.

Comment: Seems extremely advanced. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can use input boxes of required length

ex:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4">.<input type="text" maxlength="2">.<input type="text" maxlength="4">
```

Comment: So the user would have to tab to the next input, or click it? That does not sound like a great user experience.